# Showing results from multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on a legacy Access CRM, for which I have been tasked to add some extra functionality to last us until we can switch to a proper solution.

I have a series of tables representing a one-to-many connection between a Case and various types of Case Notes. These case notes all represent various types of infomation specific to a given workflow (ie an email going into our database needs to have specific fields, which are different than a call), and therefore each different kind of Case Note is represented by a different table. So my table looks something like

- Cases

  - ID
  - Title
  - etc...
- Case_Emails

  - ID
  - Case ID
  - To Email
  - From Email
  - etc...
- Case_Calls

  - ID
  - Case ID
  - Caller Email
  - etc...

Where there are some shared fields between Case Notes, such as Email. One desired feature is to filter a list of email addresses into a ComboBox, based on previous notes tied to a case along with defaults (email addresses used commonly within our day-to-day operations).

Currently, I am using VBA to open a query over each table, then I iterate over the RecordSet capturing unique values. However I would like to pull these from the same query, if possible.

I have been reading on the various type of JOINs, and I do not believe they do what I need.

Can I combine certain fields from different tables to create a list of unique values?

Comment: This isn't something you can easily do with Access or SQL. This looks like an EAV structure to me, and I'm assuming that the table "Cases" matches with at least one record from either table "Case_Emails" or "Case_Calls". If that's true, the simplest fix is to move the "To Email" and "Caller Email" to the "Cases" table called "Email". The "From Email" should probably stay put. Once the tables are normalized, it should be pretty easy to find the unique email addresses. I wouldn't loop through a recordset though. Use SQL. `SELECT DISTINCT Cases.[Email] FROM Cases;`

Comment: Have a look at UNION

Comment: @ChristopherD.: It doesn't look much like EAV to me. Just because two entities have an attribute in common doesn't necessarily mean that attribute should be extracted into a shared entity (e.g. name, price, quantity, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just after a list of emails that occur at least once in at least one of the tables, then this should do the trick.

```
SELECT t1.emailAdd from
(
select emailField as emailAdd from Case_Emails
union 
select emailField as emailAdd from Case_Calls
) t1
group by t1.emailAdd
order by t1.emailAdd
```

If it must only be emails that occur at least once in at least one of the tables and must be linked to a specific case (for example 12345), then this should do that:

```
    SELECT t1.emailAdd from
    (
    select emailField as emailAdd from Case_Emails where CaseID=12345
    union 
    select emailField as emailAdd from Case_Calls where CaseID=12345
    ) t1
    group by t1.emailAdd
    order by t1.emailAdd
```

Comment: Why `group by`? I don't see that it is doing anything.

Comment: `union` is *exactly* what I was missing, thanks a ton!

Comment: @onedaywhen The `group by` is simply to display each address only once. You could also use `DISTINCT`

Comment: Both `group by` and `distinct` are redundant because `union` has already removed duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to pull these from the same query, if possible.

Using SQL DLL while in ANSI-92 Query Mode (or do the same manually using the Access GUI tools):

```
CREATE VIEW CaseEmailAddresses ( case_id, email_address )
AS
SELECT [Case ID], [To Email] FROM Case_Emails
UNION
SELECT [Case ID], [Caller Email] FROM Case_Calls;
```

Then in SQL DML (queries):

```
SELECT email_address
  FROM CaseEmailAddresses
 WHERE case_id = <inject id here>;
```

Or while you're in ANSI-92 Query Mode, you can create a stored procedure e.g. assuming `case_id` is type integer:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetEmailAddresses ( :case_id INT )
AS
SELECT case_id, email_address
  FROM CaseEmailAddresses
 WHERE case_id = :case_id;
```

Then you can use the technology of your choice to execute this proc while passing the parameter value.